# How to access the names of tables stored in the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

I know similar questions have been asked many times. But its not working for me. I am working on windows form application. I have placed a list box in one of the forms and want it to display the names of the tables stored in the database. What query should I write to access the tables ?

```
USE db_name 
SELECT * FROM sys.Tables
```

My database name is `dbSave.mdf` but it doesnt work if I put this as db_name in the above query
Please help...

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Are you sure the user account you are using has enough access rights to perform this kind of operation?

Comment: yes access rights are not the problem....it works for .dbo database which we create for web application but for window app we dont have .dbo i suppose, so what is supposed to be written as db_name in the query ?

Comment: You cannot query a `.mdf` file directly - you must attach that file to a running instance of SQL Server first - then connect to it using the **logical** database name (not the physical `.mdf` filename)

Comment: i guess u r right.....thanx @marc_s

Comment: i have another idea to get what i need....I'm saving the tables at runtime. Why don't i just make a separate table for storing table names and then access the records of that table and display them in list box

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
```

I found it [here](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/JDBC/12858-The-query-used-to-display-all-tables-names-in-SQL-Server..html).

Comment: I'm not saying that these queries give error....but they are not showing the tables of my database (savedb.mdf)

Comment: Please see the comment by marc_s above. I must have missed that the table was a .mdf when first reading your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is different from databse to database.  Your best bet is to use some sort of abstract api.  I'm not familiar with .NET's data access but in java's libraries you use "MetaData" objects to do it.

Comment: hmmmm I'm using sql server database. I have no knowledge about java.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE Type_desc='USER_TABLE'
```

I hope this will help you :)

Also yo can create filter on schema or databse level

Answer (score 0):

I think your Query is fine to retrieve table list from a Database

```
SELECT * FROM sys.Tables
```

No need to use Use DB because your application connection string already connected with that database .
Once that is another DB please create new connection string for that database .

And also verify that your User have enough right in that working database.